# how to pass in a std::shared_ptr but do "pass by reference" job?

Tags: c++, c++11, pass-by-reference, smart-pointers

I have a main function that takes in a reference of a class object and try to update it via `foo()` and `bar()`, however, the `bar()` only allows to pass into a shared_ptr type. How can I guarantee it behaves as expected, assuming I am NOT allowed to modify the signature of `bar()`.

```
void foo(MyStruct& s) {
  modifyS(s);
}

void bar(std::shared_ptr<MyStruct> s) {
  modifySAgain(s);
}

mainFunction(MyStruct& s) {
  foo(s);
  // bar(?) how should I do here such that s would be modified by bar()
  // bar(std::make_shared<Mystruct>(std::move(s)) ?
}
```

Comment: If you are allowed to change the signature of `bar` then why not just make it `void bar(MyStruct& s)` just like `foo`?

Comment: What behavior do you expect? You should be able to modify the object in both cases.

Comment: Either `bar` actually requires a `std::shared_ptr` to work correctly, or it only requires a `MyStruct&` to work correctly. If the latter, `bar` is written incorrectly and should be fixed.

Comment: Insofar as there is a low level technical solution to your problem, it likely involves `enabled_shared_from_this`. That said, I think the design is the issue here. If bar requires ownership, and `mainFunction` calls bar, then transitively `mainFunction` requires ownership too. But free functions should relatively rarely need to take ownership anyhow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a null-aliasing shared pointer:

```
bar(std::shared_ptr<MyStruct>(std::shared_ptr<MyStruct>(), &s));
```

The temporary shared pointer created in this call shares ownership with a null shared pointer, so it does nothing on destruction.

This is perhaps a bit of a hack.

Comment: It may be hacky, but it's clever and I didn't even know this was possible. Nice. :-)

Comment: I'd appreciate a few words on how this 'hack' works.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: See constructor note 8 [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr). Basically, the outer constructor does reference counting for the first argument, but all other behaviors are in terms of the second argument. So it's managing a null pointer (the first argument), while exposing the second argument as if it were managing it. It's not safe if the function being called keeps its own copy though, since now it believes it can extend the lifetime of the value when that's not true (the lifetime of `s` is not tied to the shared pointer at all).

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: No, you don't get to keep the pointer, that's the whole point. So no need for thanks.

Comment: Can't we just all share and get along!